# vt-x error setting up vb. cant change settings

Tags: virtual-machine, ms-dos, hardware-virtualization

im trying to set up a virtual machine of dos using oracle on windows 10.
using all default settings (32mb of ram, virtual hard disk with 500mb, hard disk file type = vdi...  )

specific version of virtual box { VirtualBox Graphical User Interface
Version 6.1.2 r135662 (Qt5.6.2)
also i should mention dos 6.22
 }

i receive this error. 
how can i fix this. i just want to run a vm of dos

Not in a hypervisor partition (HVP=0) (VERR_NEM_NOT_AVAILABLE).

VT-x is disabled in the BIOS for all CPU modes (VERR_VMX_MSR_ALL_VMX_DISABLED).

Result Code: 
E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: 
ConsoleWrap
Interface: 
IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}

the common solution to this error is to go into settings and turn all acceleration options off, however i cannot accept the new settings.

in the options settings i get an error telling me to turn this off. i cannot accept settings  until error resolved, but doing what it says does not resolve the problem

evidence provided below

edit) all previous images reformed into a neater image 
[image]

Comment: Try using 16 Mb of memory as there is a limit to what DOS can address. Otherwise as suggested above, turn VT-x ON and make sure Virtualization is enabled in BIOS

Comment: in the options settings i get an error telling me to turn this off. i cannot accept settings  until error resolved, but doing what it says does not resolve the problem

Comment: the 16 mb thing didnt work i got the same error :(

Comment: and no amount of messing with the settings for acceleration allows me to click accept. this is demonstrated in the image

Comment: if by host machine you mean my laptop with windows 10, check the top right of the image. that shows that my laptop has it enabled
i will upload a second image to show no amount of messing with it makes it work

Comment: @Ramhound not even the one called  "this image shows that i recieve an error when vt-x is on" ?

Comment: @Ramhound i uploaded the screenshot. thank you by the way

Comment: @Ramhound sorry, the specific version is VirtualBox Graphical User Interface Version 6.1.2 r135662.
i think i might have fixed screenshot 4

Comment: nope :(

do i have to sacrafice a goat to make vm's work or something?

Comment: @Ramhound i did that in pick 5. still same problem.

Comment: Did you activate VT-x in the BIOS...? You've never mentioned accessing the BIOS to confirm it's activated. It often is disabled at factory settings.

Answer (score 0):

In VBox configuration settings you can set the checkbox to use VT-x. But the enable / disable VT-x can be set as the *BIOS* UEFI feature. This is the motherboard (chipset) settings, but it also depends on CPU used. All modern (at least 7years old) AMD CPU has this feature. The Intel CPU you must test. In Linux  you can simply type

```
lscpu |egrep --colour vmx
```

in console and if your CPU does not have this feature, you get no output.
If you want to use the VT-x in VBox, you have to enable the VT-x in *BIOS*. The VBox can run the virtual machine without the HW support, but in this case you VM may run less secure, reliable, performance.

Comment: Author is using a Windows host.

Comment: changing chipset settings also does not resolve the problem and allow me to click ok. new image with more evidence added

Comment: @Ramhound - I had guessed the MS-Windows host, thats why I explicitly wrote _In Linux_ . I admit I do not know how to investigate this in MS-Windows, but there is plenty of Live Linux OS bootable CD / DVD / USB so that if there is no other way Linux can be easy used. You are welcome. P.S. It should be a good practise to identify the OS with its full name **MS-Windows** not to confuse with an elder **X Windows**

Comment: @schweik - The author specifically indicates they are using Windows 10